# Failing to dual boot Ubuntu and OSX

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot, mac, grub

Let me preface this by saying that 1) I have little experience with EFI systems and 2) I have little experience with Apple systems.

System specs:

MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2011)

OSX El Capitan (Version 10.11.3)

Alright, so I'm trying to make a simple dual boot system that allows me to select an OS to boot to each time, with a default choice selected after X seconds. With legacy pc systems, this is a peice of cake. Run the Ubuntu installer and let GRUB take care of it.

With OSX, I'm having issues, mainly that it appears that I should be using rEFInd. I downloaded and ran the install script from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) but it tells me that SIP is enabled. So I launch recovery mode by holding CMD+R at boot. (this is another problem that could be related- it launches internet recovery mode instead of just regular recovery mode, and therefore takes about an hour to do so). So anyway, once that finally loads, I open terminal and run `csrutil disable`. This for whatever reason, returns command not found, implying that SIP doesn't exist, yet rEFInd claims that it is enabled.

If there is any way to do this using plain old grub, I'd be super happy. Alternatively, I'd love a way to get this darned thing to do what it's supposed to with rEFInd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, answering my own question. Well, the solution proved to be simple, yet tedious. Especially when apple makes their own HD name with a space. Who does that??? Anyway, solution as follows:

1) boot into recovery mode (for some reason still uses internet mode, but whatever)
2) cd to the directory where you have the installer located (probably `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Downloads/refind-filename` then `refind-install`). Or you may have to run the full thing as one giant mess like I did